# Greedy v/s Non-Greedy matching dilemma with python regex

Tags: python, regex

As far as I read, **?** is supposed to be the operator to indicate non-greedy(i.e. smallest first) matching in python regex. I am having trouble in relating matching for the following two similar regex strings:

**Case 1:**

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(Super|Bat|Spider|Ant){1,2}')
>>> regex.search('AntAnt-Man').group()
'AntAnt'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(Super|Bat|Spider|Ant){1,2}?')
>>> regex.search('AntAnt-Man').group()
'Ant'
```

**Case 2:**

```
>>> regex.search('AntAnt-Man').group()
'AntAnt-Man'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(Super|Bat|Spider|Ant){1,2}?-(Man)')
>>> regex.search('AntAnt-Man').group()
'AntAnt-Man'
```

**Dilemma:**
If in case1, group method picks 'Ant' if using **?**, why isn't the same happening for case2?

Comment: Because matching starts at the leftmost location. Matches are searched for from left to right.

Comment: In case 2 your pattern which includes -Man must match AntAnt-Man because a shorter match isn’t possible once the first Ant is matched. Matching against FredAnt-Man would return Ant-Man.